# How to make mozzarella with rennet?

Tags: cheese, milk, cheese-making, dairy, mozzarella

I used to make soft cheese by vinegar, which quickly results in the formation of curd. I tried to make hard cheese (mozzarella) by `rennet` (commercial tablet) by the process took more than 30min and the result was something like yogurt.

I simply followed the manual (mixing the tablet solved in warm water with the milk at temperature 35 - 40 C). Was something wrong with my procedure, milk, or rennet?

Comment: Mozzarella is not generally considered a hard cheese.

Comment: Mozzarella is a cooked cheese, you have to pull the curd in boiling water or similar (I forgot the details). Are you sure that this rennet was intended for mozzarella?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ you're right, I just want to mention the difference between the so-called `penyr` and fat cheeses like `mozzarella`.

Comment: @rumtscho the rennet table says generally cheese. As I read, it is not possible to make `mozzarella` by vinegar, and rennet is needed.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to make mozzarella with generic rennet or a special one is needed. But I can tell you that the procedure for making mozzarella is a very specific one, different from all other cheeses. So, if you are following instructions which didn't say "mozzarella", you won't end up with mozzarella. Cheese making is a large topic, you might want to get some books on it instead of relying on the instructions on the package of a random rennet.

Comment: oh, and there is no process which will make hard cheese in 30 minutes. You can get fresh mozzarella quite quickly, maybe in under an hour, but if you want dry mozzarella, you have to age it. (It isn't hard cheese even then, as SAJ suggested, for hard cheeses you need months under controlled conditions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one time I made mozzarella, I used [this recipe](http://www.cheesemaking.com/howtomakemozzarellacheese.html). As I understand it, the key is (a) citric acid, and (b) kneading (that's what gives it the stringy texture). It turned out pretty well, but it didn't keep long at all.